# Kivy grid layout fixed column width for some columns

Tags: python, image, kivy, grid-layout

I'd like to construct a grid layout where some columns have a fixed width (to contain an image) while others should take the available space. This is my current situation (last column):

[image: kivy grid layout example]

As you can see on the blue background, the columns are too large for the image. However, since there are more columns whose size should be relative to the available width, I cannot use the `col_force_default` property of the grid layout.

So is it possible to fix the width of some columns while still let the other columns take all the available space?

Here is an excerpt from my kv file:

```
<EditWorkoutExcerciseRow@GridLayout>
    exRepetitionsRound: ex_repetitions_round
    exRepetitionsText: ex_repetitions_ti
    exNameLabel: ex_name_label
    exDeleteBtn:ex_delete_btn
    exUpBtn:ex_up_btn
    exDownBtn: ex_down_btn


    TextInput:
        id: ex_repetitions_round
        multiline:False
        size_hint:(0.25,1)
        padding:(10,10,10,10)

    TextInput:
        size_hint:(0.25,1)
        id: ex_repetitions_ti
        multiline:False
        padding:(10,10,10,10)

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.5,1)
        id: ex_name_label
        text:''


    Button:
        id:ex_delete_btn
        background_normal:''
        background_pressed:''
        background_disabled:''
        background_color:(0,0,1,1)
        padding:(10,10)

        Image:
            source:'data/image/delete.png'

            size: (40,40)
            y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height + 20
            x: self.parent.x + 15
            allow_stretch: False
            keep_ratio: True

    Button:
        id:ex_up_btn
        background_normal:''
        background_pressed:''
        background_disabled:''
        background_color:(0,0,0,0)

        Image:
            source:'data/image/arrow_up.png'
            y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height + 20
            x: self.parent.x + 20
            size: '40dp', '40dp'
            allow_stretch: True
    Button:
        id:ex_down_btn
        background_normal:''
        background_pressed:''
        background_disabled:''
        background_color:(0,0,0,0)

        Image:
            source:'data/image/arrow_down.png'
            y: self.parent.y + self.parent.height + 20
            x: self.parent.x + 15
            size: 40, 40
            allow_stretch: True
```

As you can see, I experimented a bit with size values but no results so far. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding those buttons to a nested Grid layout and setting the fixed column width there.
I'd like to prevent nesting layouts more than necessary but I couldn't figure out a cleaner solution. 
If someone knows a better answer, don't hesitate to post it, I will leave it open.

```
<EditWorkoutExcerciseRow@GridLayout>
    exRepetitionsRound: ex_repetitions_round
    exRepetitionsText: ex_repetitions_ti
    exNameLabel: ex_name_label
    exDeleteBtn:ex_delete_btn
    exUpBtn:ex_up_btn
    exDownBtn: ex_down_btn


    TextInput:
        id: ex_repetitions_round
        multiline:False
        size_hint:(0.2,1)
        padding:(10,10,10,10)

    TextInput:
        size_hint:(0.2,1)
        id: ex_repetitions_ti
        multiline:False
        padding:(10,10,10,10)

    Label:
        size_hint:(0.3,1)
        id: ex_name_label
        text:''

    GridLayout:
        size_hint:(0.3,1)
        cols:3
        rows:1
        col_default_width:50
        col_force_default:True
        spacing:10,10
        Button:
            id:ex_delete_btn
            background_normal:''
            background_pressed:''
            background_disabled:''
            background_color:(0,0,0,0)
            size:50,50
            Image:
                source:'data/image/delete.png'
                size:(50,50)
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True
        Button:
            id:ex_up_btn
            background_normal:''
            background_pressed:''
            background_disabled:''
            background_color:(0,0,0,0)
            size:50,50
            Image:
                source:'data/image/arrow_up.png'
                size:(50,50)
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x
                allow_stretch: True
                keep_ratio: True


        Button:
            id:ex_down_btn
            background_normal:''
            background_pressed:''
            background_disabled:''
            background_color:(0,0,0,0)
            size:50,50
            Image:
                source:'data/image/arrow_down.png'
                y: self.parent.y
                x: self.parent.x
                size:50,50
                allow_stretch: True
```